# Создание объекта класса внутри него же самого

Tags: java

Разбираюсь в Java и возник вопрос: 
Если делаю массив `connections` статическим и использую его в методе `getElementOfArray()` то при `System.out.println(getElementOfArray());` он выводит (последний) элемент массива (что и нужно).
 Но если я хочу чтобы массив принадлежал объекту а не классу, и создаю объект `ConnectionManager`для доступа к массиву, то `System.out.println(getElementOfArray());` выводит только `null`.

**Вопрос:**

1. Какой создается объект, при `ConnectionManager cm = new ConnectionManager();`
2. Будет ли этот объект начинаться с psvm
3. Почему все-таки со статическим массивом все проходит хорошо, а при создании объекта - нет?

*Спасибо огромное*

```java
public class ConnectionManager {
    private Connection1[] connections = new Connection1[5]; //Массив для Connection1
    private static int counter;

    private void fillArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i &lt connections.length; i++) {    //Наполняет массив
            connections[i] = Connection1.getInstance();   //элементами Connection1
            counter++;
            System.out.println(connections.getClass() + " Element added");
        }
    }

    static Connection1 getElementOfArray(){
        <em>ConnectionManager cm = new ConnectionManager();</em>     //Cоздание объекта
        if(counter > 0){
            return cm.connections[--counter];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionManager cm = new ConnectionManager();
        cm.fillArray();
        System.out.println(getElementOfArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: а при дебаггинге что пишет? раз приходит null, значит там и правда 0 элементов.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator я это понимаю, но хочу понять, почему это происходит

Comment: у тебя private Connection1[] connections  не является статическим. сделай его статической и тогда будет понимать что брать. в противном случае ты обращаешься к массиву, элементы которого не заполнены и не инициализированы

Answer (score 15, accepted):

У вас создается два объекта `ConnectionManager`. В методе `main` один объект, а в методе `getElementOfArray` другой, соответственно, если массив не статический происходит обращение к разным массивам.

Т.е. метод `fillArray` заполняет массив другого объекта, к которому не происходит обращение.

Надеюсь, понятно объяснил =)

Comment: Но при создании объекта в методе `getElementOfArray()`  ,я так понимаю, должен вызываться его psvm и соответственно заполняться массив . Правильно?

Comment: psvm - это что?

Comment: Нет, не верно.  psvm здесь вызывается лишь раз, при запуске программы. fillArray заполняет совсем другой массив.

Comment: @Nikolay public static void main(String[] args){}

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov Спасибо)

Answer (score 8):

У тебя массив не заполняется. Здесь ты создаешь объект и заполняешь в нем массив:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionManager cm = new ConnectionManager();
        cm.fillArray();
        System.out.println(getElementOfArray());
    }
```

А здесь ты создаешь новый объект и ничего в нем не заполняешь:

```
static Connection1 getElementOfArray(){
        ConnectionManager cm = new ConnectionManager();     //Cоздание объекта
        if(counter > 0){
            return cm.connections[--counter];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```